# Requests / Beautiful Soup / Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am studying web scrapping and I need some help.
The page that is returning to me has a strange encoding. How can I fix this?
Why my page don't show like link below?
https://www.saraiva.com.br/redes-de-computadores-ii-niveis-de-transporte-e-rede-serie-tekne-6194354/p

[The page that is returning to me has a strange encoding. How can I fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRLxv.jpg)

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_http(url, nome_livro):

    nome_livro = nome_livro.replace(' ', '%20')
    url = '{0}?q={1}'.format(url, nome_livro)

    try:
        return requests.get(url)
    except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.RequestException,
            requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as e:

            print(str(e))
            pass
    except Exception as e:
            raise

def get_products(content):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    products = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'nm-product-img-container'}, limit = 10)

    list_products = []
    for product in products:
        info_product = [product.a.get('href').replace("//", "http://"), product.a.string]
        list_products.append(info_product)

    return list_products 

def get_http_page_product(list_products):
    
    for product in list_products:

        try:
            r = requests.get(product[0])
            print(r.url)
            print(r.encoding)
            '''r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'''

        except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as e:
                print(str(e))
                r = None
        except Exception as e:
                raise    

        print(product[0])
        print(product[1])        
        parse_page_product(r.text, product[0], product[1]) 
        break   

def parse_page_product(content, url_product, title):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    with open('result.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)     

if __name__=='__main__':
    url = 'http://busca.saraiva.com.br/busca'         
    nome_livro = 'redes de computadores'

    r = get_http(url, nome_livro)

    if r:
        list_products = get_products(r.text)
        get_http_page_product(list_products)
```

Comment: How about showing your code? And with that I mean code, **NOT** screenshots of code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't see the page in code like in a browser is that it is loaded dynamically. If you understand how requests work in the browser, you can find the request to the API. Using the link you chose as an example, I will show you how to get title, description, pictures, sellers and prices. Then you choose the fields you need. To do this, we only need to know the product SKU. First of all, we will connect the necessary libraries

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
```

Now let's prepare the get SKU function

```
def get_sku(url):
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')
    return soup.find('meta', {"itemprop": "sku"}).get('content')
```

Now we have received the SKU and can substitute it in the API.

```
def get_product_details(sku):
    url = f"https://www.saraiva.com.br/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search?fq=skuId:{sku}"
    headers = {
        'accept': '*/*'
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    json_obj = json.loads(response.text)
    print(json_obj[0]['productTitle'])
    print(json_obj[0]['description'])
    for item in json_obj[0]['items']:
        for images in item['images']:
            print(images['imageUrl'])
        for seller in item['sellers']:
            print(seller['sellerName'], seller['commertialOffer']['Price'])
```

Now we just have to pass the reference to our function and we can look at the result

```
get_product_details(get_sku("https://www.saraiva.com.br/redes-de-computadores-ii-niveis-de-transporte-e-rede-serie-tekne-6194354/p"))
```

Output:

```
Redes de Computadores II - Níveis de Transporte e Rede - Série Tekne
Com o intuito de oferecer os subsídios necessários para a formação qualificada na área, esta obra aborda a conceituação e aplicação dos protocolos de redes e dos equipamentos de comunicação de dados, especificamente na camada de transporte e rede. Este livro é uma parceria das editoras do Grupo A Educação com o IFRS (Instituto Federal de Educação, Ciência e Tecnologia do Rio Grande do Sul).
https://lojasaraiva.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/9206261/1008454251.jpg?v=637103785666070000
Saraiva 77.0
```